# Change XML with XSLT different Values

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an Problem with Converting XML with XSLT to another XML.

I get this Code from Management System:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <DocumentElement>
        <article>
            <ordernumber>100002</ordernumber>
            <mainnumber>100002</mainnumber>
            <ItmsGrpNam>Lager</ItmsGrpNam>
            <name>7006CYDU/GM</name>
            <suppliername>Nachi</suppliername>
            <active>1</active>
            <Price>0.000000</Price>
            <propertyGroupName>1A</propertyGroupName> 
            <propertyOptionName>1B</propertyOptionName>
            <propertyValueName>1C</propertyValueName>
            <propertyGroupName1>2A</propertyGroupName1> 
            <propertyOptionName1>2B</propertyOptionName1>
            <propertyValueName1>2C</propertyValueName1>
            <propertyGroupName2>3A</propertyGroupName2> 
            <propertyOptionName2>3B</propertyOptionName2>
            <propertyValueName2>3C</propertyValueName2>
       </article>
   </DocumentElement>
```

But i need this Format:

```
<propertyValue>
    <propertyGroupName>1A</propertyGroupName>
    <propertyValueName>1B</propertyValueName>
    <propertyOptionName>1C</propertyOptionName>
</propertyValue>
<propertyValue>
    <propertyGroupName>2A</propertyGroupName>
    <propertyValueName>2B</propertyValueName>
    <propertyOptionName>2C</propertyOptionName>
</propertyValue>
<propertyValue>
    <propertyGroupName>3A</propertyGroupName>
    <propertyValueName>3B</propertyValueName>
    <propertyOptionName>3C</propertyOptionName>
</propertyValue>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Root>
    <articles>
      <xsl:for-each select="DocumentElement/article">
        <article>
          <ordernumber><xsl:value-of select="ordernumber"/></ordernumber>
          <mainnumber><xsl:value-of select="mainnumber"/></mainnumber>
          <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
          <supplier><xsl:value-of select="suppliername"/></supplier>
          <tax>19</tax>
          <prices>
            <price>
              <price><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></price>
            </price>
          </prices>
          <active><xsl:value-of select="active"/></active>
          <category>
            <categories>
             <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="ItmsGrpNam='Lager'">39</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="ItmsGrpNam='Transistor'">40</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="ItmsGrpNam='Dichtring'">41</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="ItmsGrpNam='Schütz'">42</xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
           </categories>
         </category>
         <propertyValue>
           <propertyGroupName><xsl:value-of select="propertyGroupName"/> </propertyGroupName>
           <propertyOptionName><xsl:value-of select="propertyOptionName"/></propertyOptionName>
           <propertyValueName><xsl:value-of select="propertyValueName"/></propertyValueName>
           </propertyValue>
        </article>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </articles>
</Root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me of course just one property block back:

```
<propertyValue>
            <propertyGroupName>1A</propertyGroupName>
            <propertyOptionName>1B</propertyOptionName>
            <propertyValueName>1C</propertyValueName>
</propertyValue>
```

I want this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <articles>
        <article>
            <ordernumber>100002</ordernumber>
            <mainnumber>100002</mainnumber>
            <name>7006CYDU/GM</name>
            <supplier>Nachi</supplier>
            <tax>19</tax>
            <prices>
                <price>
                    <price>0.000000</price>
                </price>
            </prices>
            <active>1</active>
            <category>
                <categories>39</categories>
            </category>
            <propertyValue>
                <propertyGroupName>1A</propertyGroupName>
                <propertyOptionName>1B</propertyOptionName>
                <propertyValueName>1C</propertyValueName>
            </propertyValue>
            <propertyValue>
                <propertyGroupName>2A</propertyGroupName>
                <propertyOptionName>2B</propertyOptionName>
                <propertyValueName>2C</propertyValueName>
            </propertyValue>
            <propertyValue>
                <propertyGroupName>3A</propertyGroupName>
                <propertyOptionName>3B</propertyOptionName>
                <propertyValueName>3C</propertyValueName>
            </propertyValue>
        </article>
    </articles>
</Root>
```

Is it possible to make an query to get this Format from all other propertyGroupName1, propertyGroupName2 [...]?

chrisen

Comment: **1.** Will there always be exactly 3 groups of properties or can there be any number? -- **2.** Please post the **exact** output (in full) you want to get.

Comment: No there are sometimes 2 groups, sometimes 20

Comment: The full output code is edited to the main question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
    <Root>
        <articles>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </articles>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ordernumber | mainnumber | name | suppliername"/>
        <tax>19</tax>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Price"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="active"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ItmsGrpNam"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'propertyGroupName')]">
            <propertyValue>
                <propertyGroupName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </propertyGroupName>
                <propertyOptionName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'propertyOptionName')][1]"/>              
                </propertyOptionName>
                <propertyValueName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'propertyValueName')][1]"/>                               
                </propertyValueName>
            </propertyValue>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="suppliername">
    <supplier>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </supplier>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Price">
    <prices>
        <price>
            <price>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </price>
        </price>
    </prices>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ItmsGrpNam">
    <category>
        <categories>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=".='Lager'">39</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=".='Transistor'">40</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=".='Dichtring'">41</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=".='Schütz'">42</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </categories>
    </category>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```